# why C++ destuctor affect the behavior of return value optimization

Tags: c++, destructor, rvo

I have simplified my code as follows.

```
#include <vector>
class NoncopyableItem {
 public:
  NoncopyableItem() { }
  NoncopyableItem(NoncopyableItem &&nt) { };
};
class Iterator {
  friend class Factory;
 public:
  ~Iterator() { }  // weird
 private:
  Iterator() { }
  std::vector<NoncopyableItem> buffer_;
};
class Factory {
 public:
  Iterator NewIterator() {
    return Iterator();
  }
};
int main() {
  Factory fa;
  auto it = fa.NewIterator();
  return 0;
}
```

I want to leverage the RVO (return value optimization) in function `NewIterator`, but I got the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/vector:62:0,
                 from /cygdrive/c/Users/DELL/ClionProjects/destructor_test/main.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = NoncopyableItem; _Args = {const NoncopyableItem&}]':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:75:53:   required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const NoncopyableItem*, std::vector<NoncopyableItem> >; _ForwardIterator = NoncopyableItem*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:126:41:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const NoncopyableItem*, std::vector<NoncopyableItem> >; _ForwardIterator = NoncopyableItem*]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:279:63:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const NoncopyableItem*, std::vector<NoncopyableItem> >; _ForwardIterator = NoncopyableItem*; _Tp = NoncopyableItem]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:324:32:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = NoncopyableItem; _Alloc = std::allocator<NoncopyableItem>]'
/cygdrive/c/Users/DELL/ClionProjects/destructor_test/main.cpp:7:7:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function 'constexpr NoncopyableItem::NoncopyableItem(const NoncopyableItem&)'
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^
/cygdrive/c/Users/DELL/ClionProjects/destructor_test/main.cpp:2:7: note: 'constexpr NoncopyableItem::NoncopyableItem(const NoncopyableItem&)' is implicitly declared as deleted because 'NoncopyableItem' declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
 class NoncopyableItem {
       ^
CMakeFiles/destructor_test.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/destructor_test.dir/main.cpp.o' failed
```

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), `NewIterator()` should meet the requirement of RVO. However, it seems that the compiler trys to call the default copy constructor of `Iterator`, then fails because `Iterator.buffer_` is noncopyable.

Well, to my suprise, if I delete the destructor of `Iterator` in L#13, the code works fine.

Why does the destructor affect the RVO behavior of the compiler?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, forget about RVO in this context. It is a legal optimization, but even when it does happen, the code must be legal without it.

So with this in mind, we look at

```
auto it = fa.NewIterator();
```

This line attempts to construct a new `Iterator` from a temporary `Iterator`. For this to work, we need either of the following two<sup>†</sup>:

```
Iterator(const Iterator&); //or
Iterator(Iterator&&);
```

Now in the code you posted, trying to use the implicitly declared `Iterator(const Iterator&);` will result in the compiler error you showed because the copy constructor of the non-static member `buffer_` fails to compile.

The second candidate is not generated because `Iterator` has a user defined destructor.

If you remove the user defined destructor, the compiler will generate the move constructor `Iterator(Iterator&&);` and use it as we are constructing from a temporary. Or maybe it won't and do RVO instead, but it *could* use it, and that is the important part.

---

<sup>†</sup>Or some other user declared constructor that makes the line legal of course. But above are the two commonly compiler generated ones you apparently ask about.

Comment: Not quite right. `Iterator(const Iterator&);` will be implicitly declared and defined as defaulted (not deleted). However, the copy constructor of `std::vector<NoncopyableItem>` will fail to instantiate. (`std::vector<NoncopyableItem>` has an accessible copy constructor as far as the check for member copyability is concerned.) Hence the OP's error.

Comment: @T.C. Thank you, fixed. It will however be defined as deleted as of 12.7/11 in N4140, right?

Comment: No, `Iterator`'s copy constructor is not actually deleted, because the vector nominally *does have* an accessible and non-deleted copy constructor. `static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<Iterator>{}, "");` will *not* fire. The implicit definition of `Iterator`'s copy constructor triggers the instantiation of the vector's copy constructor, which causes a hard error.